# Advice/Opinion: Insert Data to a specific user using Firebase and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, insert

I would really like some advice and opinion I am now currently inserting data from firebase using angular. I can now insert data but the problem is It won't insert inside the child I' am calling.

This is my **task-form.component.html**:

```
<form #t="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="add(t.value)">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="taskTechiciansName">Technicians Name</label>

<select ngModel name="taskTechniciansName" id="taskTechniciansName" 
class="form-control">
   <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let a of techNames$ | async" [value] ="a.$key">
    {{ a.name }}
   </option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="taskAdd">Address</label>
   <input ngModel name="taskAdd" id="taskAdd" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="taskDate">Date</label>
   <input ngModel name="taskDate" id="taskDate" type="date" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="taskClass">Class</label>
   <input ngModel name="taskClass" id="taskClass" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="taskDesc">Description</label>
   <input ngModel name="taskDesc" id="taskDesc" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Add Task</button>
</form>
```

here is my code **tasks.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class TaskService {

uid: string;

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, 
private af: AngularFireDatabase, 
private am: AngularFireAuthModule
) {
}

create(tasks){
return this.db.database.ref('/users/').push({ tasks }).key;
}
}
```

and this is my database structure:

[image: firebase database]

and this is how the data is being submitted:

[task data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1H61.png)

I really want to **insert the info data into a specific user under tasks child**. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake is a simple typo: you're missing a `/` in the path:

```
create(tasks){
  return this.db.database.ref('/users/' + this.uid).push({ tasks }).key;
}
```

The second mistake is just as simple: you never give `uid` a value, so it's `undefined`. I'm just not sure how to fix it, since it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I already tried it but it still won't store inside the ifno it will create another child name undefined.

Comment: The missing `/` is the first mistake. The second mistake is that you're not setting `uid` anywhere.

Comment: where do I have to set the uid ? im sorry im just a beginner.

Comment: If you want it to be the UID of the current user, you'll want to do something like the docs say here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user

Comment: the UID is not for the current user. this is for admin side and admin side can add task to different user. Im using dropdown list to call the technician, I can also store the data now inside the users child but the data  for info should be stored inside a specific user.